# How can I define a default client view in Perforce?

Tags: perforce

When creating a new client workspace in Perforce, the default view contains the entire depot (or, more correctly, all of the depots defined on the server). This is never needed, yet new users often leave it at that, pulling the entire depot contents to their disk.

How can I change the default view that Perforce offers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on whether you're the perforce administrator or not.

If you are, you can use [triggers](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r11.1/manuals/p4sag/06_scripting.html#1062348).

> Example: The default Perforce client workspace view maps the entire depot //depot/... to the user's client workspace. To prevent novice users from attempting to sync the entire depot, this Perl script changes a default workspace view of //depot/... in the p4 client form to map only the current release codeline of //depot/releases/main/...

If you're not the administrator, then you will have to use a template file.

`p4 client -t <template_file> <client_name>`.